# Wait until canvas.toBlob() has finished?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm converting multiple canvas elements to blobs with an `each()` loop, after which I send it to the server with AJAX.

I ran into a rather odd issue, being that the rest of my script keeps executing even if `toBlob()` is seemingly still busy.

```
// Empty array for blobs
var blobs = [];

// Loop through cropped images
myImages.each( function() {
    var thisImage = $(this);

    // Make canvas object from image
    thisImage.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {
        'width': parseInt(thisImage.attr('data-width')),
        'height': parseInt(thisImage.attr('data-height'))

    // Create blob
    }).toBlob( function(blob) {

        // Add blob to blobs array
        blobs.push(blob);

    }, 'image/jpeg', 0.75);
});

console.log(blobs.length); // Returns 0

if ( blobs.length > 0 ) {
    console.log(blobs) // Does not execute because blobs has a length of 0
}
```

The strange thing is, when I add a `setTimeout` around my `if` statement, it does execute.

```
setTimeout( function() {

    console.log(blobs.length); // Returns 2

    if ( blobs.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(blobs); // Does execute
    }

}, 5000);
```

How can I make sure the toBlob function has finished processing my blobs before attempting to send them to the server with AJAX?

Comment: That's what the callback is good for… And since you need to wait for multiple blobs, I'd recommend to use promises.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice candidate for using promises, and in particular `Promise.all`:

```
// Map the array of images to an array of promises
var promises = Array.from(myImages, function(img) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        var thisImage = $(img);
        // Make canvas object from image
        thisImage.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {
            'width': parseInt(thisImage.attr('data-width')),
            'height': parseInt(thisImage.attr('data-height'))
        // Create blob
        //  and when called back, resolve the promise with the blob value
        }).toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg', 0.75);
    });
});

// When all promises have resolved, use the resulting array of blobs:
Promise.all(promises, function (blobs) {
    console.log(blobs);
});
```